Why does floating-point output differ across platforms?
As far as I know, due to the IEEE 754 standard, extremely large numbers inputted by the user is not stored precisely in binary format. When such imprecisely stored values are converted back to decimal for display on the console, should the output remain consistent across different operating systems (Windows/Linux) and CPU architectures?
I'm asking because my client is using JDBC, and we noticed that the output values differ between Windows and Linux environments. For instance, after storing 123456.6543214586532653516 in the database and printing it to the console from both Linux and Windows systems, the results are different:
Linux:   123456.65432145866000000000
Windows: 123456.65432145864000000000

I understand that the input value cannot be precisely stored due to the limitations of floating-point representation, but I don't understand why the console output differs depending on the environment.
To investigate further, I tested the same value in both Python and Java on my x86 Windows and x86 Linux environments. Specifically, I assigned the value 123456.6543214586532653516 to a variable and printed it directly to the console. In both environments, the output was consistently 123456.65432145866 regardless of the operating system or virtual machine.
Can someone explain what might be causing this inconsistency?

This issue, to be more specific, originates from a question my colleague received from a customer. Since this is not a question I received directly and because my colleague and I handle different tasks, the information I have is unfortunately limited to what I'm sharing here. Both my colleague and I work for a database company called Tibero, which supports queries similar to those in Oracle. The customer reported that they are getting different results on Windows and Linux when running the same Java code. Unfortunately, the Java code belongs to the customer, so we cannot share it. However, the customer mentioned that the following SQL query, executed in tbsql—our company's CLI tool similar to sqlplus—also produces the same discrepancy:
CREATE TABLE convert_test(c1 BINARY_DOUBLE);
INSERT INTO convert_test VALUES(123456.6543214586532653516);
SELECT TO_CHAR(c1, '999999999999999D9999999999999999999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.'''') AS formatted_value
FROM convert_test;

Unfortunately, I couldn't reproduce the issue in my environment. I understand that Tibero might not be a familiar or easily accessible product for you, and I appreciate the challenges this might pose in arriving at an answer.
Just to check, I also installed PostgreSQL on both Windows and Linux and executed the following query. The results were consistent across platforms, with no differences:
CREATE TABLE convert_test (
    c1 DOUBLE PRECISION
);
INSERT INTO convert_test VALUES (123456.6543214586532653516);
SELECT C1 FROM CONVERT_TEST;

         c1
--------------------
 123456.65432145866


There is a known difference in the way Java does double-string conversions compared to C. Is it possible that part of your processing pipeline (JDBC driver?) uses C routines on one platform but pure Java on the other?

How exactly are you printing the values?  From the database itself, like a MySQL command line separate from Java?  According to https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=049050051052053054046054053052051050049052053056054053051050054053051053049054 the nearest representable double to 123456.6543214586532653516 is approximately 123456.65432145865634083748, so rounding to ...66 is correct, ...64 is farther from the rounded value.  What's printing with so many trailing zeros? That's not correct for double or float; https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

You haven't shown the code used to print those numbers. Provide a [MRE].

I forgot to put the code here. my bad. When I go to the work tomorrow, ill edit the post and add the code. Actually this question comes from my customer, and I cannot regenerate what my customer got.

Include in the [mre] the database schema, name of the database engine, version of JDBC drivers, and and JDBC configurations/params. The difference could be on the database response for all we know. Also which JDK version (exact)? Are you using exactly the same JDK version in both operating systems?

Seems Linux is doing the expected Round to nearest, ties to even (or maybe Round to nearest, ties away from zero, or directed rounding towards positive infinity), whereas Windows is "incorrectly"/"unexpectedly"/etc. doing directed rounding towards zero, or directed rounding towards negative infinity.  See my comment in Eric Postpischil answer (and/or his reply).

Java mandates round-to-nearest. If your client system rounds differently, then either part of your application uses C routines and fell prey to an unexpected change in the rounding mode or your Java runtime is buggy in a way that should be very obvious and highly unlikely in a widely used distribution. We can't help with either because the bug is in code that we can't see

@Steve Summit This has now been shown to be wrong (assuming you agree with the existence of an objective reality).  Telling a customer that different systems giving different results is insignificant is a non-starter in my decades of experience.  Please explain further why BigDecimal would not address this specific problem (as opposed to lecture me on my lack of understanding, or talk about the other problems of BigDecimal etc.), with functional example(s) and/or specific references.  Thank you in advance.

@Andrew I am not going to get into a long argument with you, and this
comment box is not big enough to address all the points you've raised.
(1) I'm not sure what you mean by "This has now been shown".
(2) I've dealt with unreasonable customers, too.  Sometimes they're wrong,
and sometimes you either have to tell them so, or compromise and give them
a wrong solution.
(3) There's nothing wrong with BigDecimal; it's a fine package;
I did not disrecommend it.
(4) BigDecimal might be a solution here, but we now know that the
poster can't use it; the Java code involved here isn't his.

(5) I stand by my assertion that when someone gets unexpectedly
differing or "wrong" floating-point results, a suggestion that they
use a software emulation of decimal arithmetic is not always appropriate.
(6) Floating-point results often vary slightly, due to platform
differences or for any number of other reasons, so expecting
identical results sometimes is completely unreasonable.
(7) Please be a little less defensive, if you can.  I was not lecturing you.
(I'm lecturing anyone who's listening, and who wants to learn about this stuff.)

This is very likely a rounding error, as the math below shows:
Converting the integer part:
123456  /   2   =   61728   R   0
61728   /   2   =   30864   R   0
30864   /   2   =   15432   R   0
15432   /   2   =   7716    R   0
7716    /   2   =   3858    R   0
3858    /   2   =   1929    R   0
1929    /   2   =   964 R   1
964 /   2   =   482 R   0
482 /   2   =   241 R   0
241 /   2   =   120 R   1
120 /   2   =   60  R   0
60  /   2   =   30  R   0
30  /   2   =   15  R   0
15  /   2   =   7   R   1
7   /   2   =   3   R   1
3   /   2   =   1   R   1
1   /   2   =   0   R   1

So, 12345610 in base 10 = 11110001001000000 in base 2.
digit count:              12345678901234567
                                   1      1

Converting fractional part:
0.6543214586532653516   x   2   =   1.3086429173065307032
0.3086429173065307032   x   2   =   0.6172858346130614064
0.6172858346130614064   x   2   =   1.2345716692261228128
0.2345716692261228128   x   2   =   0.4691433384522456256
0.4691433384522456256   x   2   =   0.9382866769044912512
0.9382866769044912512   x   2   =   1.8765733538089825024
0.8765733538089825024   x   2   =   1.7531467076179650048
0.7531467076179650048   x   2   =   1.5062934152359300096
0.5062934152359300096   x   2   =   1.0125868304718600192
0.0125868304718600192   x   2   =   0.0251736609437200384
0.0251736609437200384   x   2   =   0.0503473218874400768
0.0503473218874400768   x   2   =   0.1006946437748801536
0.1006946437748801536   x   2   =   0.2013892875497603072
0.2013892875497603072   x   2   =   0.4027785750995206144
0.4027785750995206144   x   2   =   0.8055571501990412288
0.8055571501990412288   x   2   =   1.6111143003980824576
0.6111143003980824576   x   2   =   1.2222286007961649152
0.2222286007961649152   x   2   =   0.4444572015923298304
0.4444572015923298304   x   2   =   0.8889144031846596608
0.8889144031846596608   x   2   =   1.7778288063693193216
0.7778288063693193216   x   2   =   1.5556576127386386432
0.5556576127386386432   x   2   =   1.1113152254772772864
0.1113152254772772864   x   2   =   0.2226304509545545728
0.2226304509545545728   x   2   =   0.4452609019091091456
0.4452609019091091456   x   2   =   0.8905218038182182912
0.8905218038182182912   x   2   =   1.7810436076364365824
0.7810436076364365824   x   2   =   1.5620872152728731648
0.5620872152728731648   x   2   =   1.1241744305457463296
0.1241744305457463296   x   2   =   0.2483488610914926592
0.2483488610914926592   x   2   =   0.4966977221829853184
0.4966977221829853184   x   2   =   0.9933954443659706368
0.9933954443659706368   x   2   =   1.9867908887319412736
0.9867908887319412736   x   2   =   1.9735817774638825472
0.9735817774638825472   x   2   =   1.9471635549277650944
0.9471635549277650944   x   2   =   1.8943271098555301888
0.8943271098555301888   x   2   =   1.7886542197110603776
0.7886542197110603776   x   2   =   1.5773084394221207552
0.5773084394221207552   x   2   =       1.xxx...
So, 0.654321458653265351610 in base 10 ~= 0.10100111100000011001110001110001111111 in base 2.
digit count:                                12345678901234567890123456789012345678
                                                     1         2         3     ^ 3
                                                                               ^   
                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                                                    the least significant bit

No further fractional digits need to be calculated since 17 + 38 = 55 = 53 bits of significand + 2 extra bits to show that this should be rounded up.
Merging these two results and dropping the extra bits:
123456.6543214586532653516 in base 10 = 11110001001000000.101001111000000110011100011100011111 in base 2.

Rounding up and shifting the radix:
1.1110001001000000101001111000000110011100011100100000 x 2^16 in base 2 = 123456.6543214586563408374786376953125

Whereas, without rounding up:
1.1110001001000000101001111000000110011100011100011111 x 2^16 in base 2 = 123456.654321458641788922250270843505859375

Since Java uses only just enough decimal digits to uniquely distinguish the number (and then zero padded if needed), these two numbers reduce to:
123456.65432145864 and 
123456.65432145866 (note the re-rounding here, aka "double rounding").

Refer to https://numeral-systems.com/ieee-754-converter/ and https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#dndec

Thank you for your detailed response. I can see that you spent a lot of time putting it together. It reminds me of the floating-point conversion methods I learned in university. When I first read your explanation, it took me a bit of time to process because I had completely forgotten how to convert —haha.

So, is it highly likely that the difference comes from the fact that the Windows Java implementation does not perform rounding up and shifting of the radix?

As a side note, I noticed your suggestion to use the BigDecimal class. It’s a great idea. However, I’m part of a team working primarily with C rather than Java, and I posed this question out of pure curiosity. My colleague told the client that the differences were likely due to platform-specific behavior. However, to be honest, we weren’t exactly sure of the root cause—whether it stemmed from the OS, the compiler, or Java itself.

What version of Java is being used (on each platform)?  There have been bugs identified and fixed in this part of the codebase.

Your colleague might want to use (or suggest to the customer to use) strictfp in Java to ensure platform-independent floating-point computations.  Refer to https://www.baeldung.com/java-strictfp, which also has an assert that tests proper rounding.  The standard is to round to nearest, where ties round to the nearest even digit based on the 3 bits that underflow, aka the guard, round, and sticky bits.  If these bits are 101 or more then round up, if 011 or less leave result alone (aka round down), if 100 then look at the least significant bit...(see next comment)

...(continuation from last comment) if the least significant bit (in case where guard, round, and sticky bits are 100, respectively) is 1 then round up which will flip the least significant bit to 0 and produce a carry, otherwise leave the result alone (aka round down).

The Windows implementation is defective; it incorrectly converted the input or source text “123456.6543214586532653516” to the IEEE-754 binary64 123456.654321458641788922250270843505859375 instead of to the correct value 123456.6543214586563408374786376953125. (I reach this conclusion based on it being the shortest path of errors to produce the observed behavior: a simple input conversion error fully explains the output.)
Printing these later with formatting to 20 digits after the decimal places produce “123456.65432145864000000000” and “123456.65432145866000000000” due to Java’s rules that formatting does not directly produce the operand converted to decimal but rather first determines a numeral with just enough decimal digits to uniquely distinguish the number within the set of Double values and then rounds that numeral to the requested length (if the requested length is shorter) or appends zeros (if the requested length is longer).

@Andrew: 123456.654321458641788922250270843505859375 is the next representable binary64 below 123456.6543214586563408374786376953125. The former is 0x1.E240A7819C720p+16. The latter is 0x1.E240A7819C71Fp+16.

@Andrew: No. Guard, round, and sticky bits are primarily relevant to hardware implementations of addition and subtraction. The conversion of a decimal numeral to a binary floating-point number is a different matter, and it is fairly complicated to do it both quickly and accurately. Microsoft has deficiencies in this area generally, so it would not surprise me if their software is involved in this Java issue and it is simply a case of a substandard defective algorithm.

The analysis at https://numeral-systems.com/ieee-754-converter/ makes sense to me, but I can't say from what's provided here if that is how it actually works.  MS, to me, is just plain bad in far too many cases to waste any more of my valuable God given hours on.  Maybe the OP will post more system/code info later.
